# program to find factorial and its reverse in a single program through recursion

Tags: java

I am aware about what is factorial. eg 5! = 5x4x3x2x1
Can anyone guide about the code to calculate the following for a number through recursion.
eg: for 5, how to calculate 5x4x3x2x1x2x3x4x5 through recursion

Comment: Just run the standard factorial twice.

Comment: Square the values during the recursion, since `5x4x3x2x1x2x3x4x5` is equivalent to `5x5x4x4x3x3x2x2x1x1` which is `(5^2)x(4^2)x(3^2)x(2^2)x(1^2)`. As for the actual recursion, there are plently of examples already existing, if you bother to look for them.

Comment: This is just `(5!)**2`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort has been made to resolve or look for a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "gimme teh codez" / "do my work for me." Stack Overflow isn't a free code-writing service or a "do my work for me" site, so zero-effort requirements dumps are completely unacceptable here.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code to solve your problem. In the last line, I am multiplying the `n` with another `n` since I need to multiply it twice, but I am keeping that multiplication in stack and pending it as I am calling the recursion. Hence at the last I am getting the result as `5*4*3*2*1*2*3*4*5=14400`.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String... args){
        int f=5;
        System.out.println(fact(f));
    }
    public static int fact(int n){
        if(n==1) return n;
        return n*fact(n-1)*n;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked for me. thanks. i knew it could be done by squares but the format specified by you was the exact thing that was missing in my head.